# Coefficients of Fourier series such that $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}c^2_{n}<\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, lp-spaces

Suppose $f \in L^1(0,\pi), f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}c_{n}\sin(nx).$ I need to understand when $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}c^2_{n}<\infty$.

By Riesz–Fischer theorem if $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}c^2_{n}<\infty$ then there exists a function $f$ such that $f$ is square-integrable and the values $c_{n}$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f$. How can we prove that there are no such functions in $L^1 \setminus L^2$?

Comment: Hints: The interval $(0, \pi)$ is bounded; and function can fail to be in $L^{1}$ only by "growing too fast", but if $1 < |f|$, then $|f| < |f|^{2}$. (On an unbounded interval, a function can fail to be in $L^{1}$ by "not dying fast enough at $\infty$", which allows $L^{2}$ functions that are not $L^{1}$.)

Comment: Are you asking how to prove the Riesz-Fischer theorem? Reading your post it _appears_ that you're asking how we can show that there are no square-integrable functions in $L^1\setminus L^2$, which is of course a silly question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $f$ be the function defined in the first paragraph of the question, and denote by $g$ the function belonging to
$L^2(0, \pi )$,  given by Riesz--Fischer, such that $\hat g(n)=c_{n}$,  for every $n$.

It then follows that $f-g$ lies in $L^1$ and
$$
  \widehat{f-g}(n)= 0, \quad\forall n\in {\mathbb N},
  $$
so $f=g$ a.e., and hence $f\in  L_2$.

Comment: "including of course every f in L1" why is it obvious?

Comment: Sorry, besides my mistake, I totally misunderstood your question the first time. I hope everything is now fixed.

Comment: @ Ruy Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!